# Where clause to select records which are greater than 3 days but exclude weekend days (Saturday and Sunday)

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to select records in SQL Server which are greater than 3 days than the current date but I need to exclude weekend days (Saturday and Sunday).

The following SQL script works to select records older than 3 days:

```
select * from [dbo].[tb_Schedule]
WHERE date >= DATEADD(day, -3, GETDATE())
```

But the problem is I don't know how to exclude weekend days.

I know that the following Where clause is used to exclude weekend days but I don't know how to implement it in the above where clause

```
WHERE ((DATEPART(dw, date_created) + @@DATEFIRST) % 7) NOT IN (0, 1)
```

Please assist how I can select records which are greater than 3 days but exclude weekend days. Thanks

Comment: You should look into a calendar table. There are thousands of examples all over the internet. Then this becomes pretty simple and allows additional flexibility like skipping holidays and such.

Comment: If you're excluding weekends, shouldn't you exclude holidays as well? As Sean mentioned, a calendar table is helpful on this.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a formula with example on how to exclude the weekends. As we've mentioned before, consider using a calendar table as you might want to exclude holidays.

```
SELECT calDate, 
    DATENAME( dw, calDate), 
    DATEADD( DD, -( 3 + CASE WHEN DATEDIFF( DD, '19000106', calDate)%7 <= 2 THEN DATEDIFF( DD, '19000106', calDate)%7
                            WHEN DATEDIFF( DD, '19000106', calDate)%7 = 3 THEN 2
                            ELSE 0 END), calDate)
FROM (VALUES( CAST( '20190201' AS date)),
            ( CAST( '20190202' AS date)),
            ( CAST( '20190203' AS date)),
            ( CAST( '20190204' AS date)),
            ( CAST( '20190205' AS date)),
            ( CAST( '20190206' AS date)),
            ( CAST( '20190207' AS date)),
            ( CAST( '20190208' AS date)),
            ( CAST( '20190209' AS date)),
            ( CAST( '20190210' AS date)),
            ( CAST( '20190211' AS date)),
            ( CAST( '20190212' AS date)),
            ( CAST( '20190213' AS date)),
            ( CAST( '20190214' AS date)),
            ( CAST( '20190215' AS date)))x(calDate);
```

Comment: Thanks. I am busy having a look at calendar tables now.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just excluding weekends and not holidays, you can just join the clauses with `AND`. This one uses `WEEKDAY` with `DATEPART` because it's easier to read. This won't work with holidays, though.

```
SELECT * 
FROM [dbo].[tb_Schedule]
WHERE 
    [date] >= DATEADD(DAY, -3, GETDATE())
    AND DATEPART(WEEKDAY,[date]) NOT IN (1,7)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from [dbo].[tb_Schedule]
where date >= DATEADD(DD, -3 -case SIGN((DATEPART(DW, GETDATE()) + @@DATEFIRST + 5) % 7 - 3)
        when -1 then 2 else 0 end, GETDATE())
```

It only failed if you call this *select* on Sundays (returns only 2 days).

Also if you want only the ***date*** part of GetDate(), you can replace the last `GETDATE()` with `FLOOR(CAST(GETDATE() as real))`